# Pass an option to a method only if a condition is true. Elegant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, haml

I have a partial that inserts in my forms the appropriate input according to the model's attribute type. I pass an array of attribute names and my partial puts a form.text_field where the attribute is a string, a form.select when the attribute is an integer (I also have a way to find the collection of text values associated to a attribute) and so on with datetime, ect.

The problem is that partial need to be as generic as possible, so I want to check if I have a params[:search][:attr_name] to set the default value, and if a don't have it, I use the default call, that sets the value of the model in the form.

Of course, i can do somethig like this (I use HAML) works:

```
- if search_param(field)
  = form.text_field field, :value => search_param(field)
- else
  = form.text_field field
```

but it's really ugly. There is any way to pass an option to a method only if a condition is true. Something like this.

```
= form.text_field field, (:value => search_param(field) ) if search_param(field)
```

I tried also to do:

```
= form.text_field field, :value => search_param(field) || field.to_sym
```

but it shows "field" inside the input

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the result you want, but what if you instead of field.to_sym use model.send(field) to get the attribute value from the model? So it would be something like this:

```
= form.text_field field, :value => ( search_param(field) || model.send(field) )
```

Comment: Yeah! It works. Only needs a few twaeks. First: get the model of the form. Second: check if form.object its not NIL, because if a use that partial inside a field_for, form doesn's has.

= form.text_field field, :value => (search_param(field) || (form.object.send(field) if form.object) )

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using the trinary operator:

```
form.text_field *([field] + (search_param(field) ? [:value => search_param(field)] : []))
```